# Same global variable access issue declared in two methods WP Json API Plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, plugins

```
public function getDVCLoanResortData() {
        global $wpdb;
        global $json_api;
        $company_id = $json_api->query->company_id;
        $resort_code = $json_api->query->resort_code;
        return array('resort_data' => $wpdb->get_row("Select * From wp_loan_resorts WHERE company_id={$company_id} AND resort_code = '{$resort_code}'", ARRAY_A));
    }
```

Above method is called in another method below.

```
public function getDVCLoanAmount(){

        global $json_api;
        $resort_data = $this->getDVCLoanResortData()['resort_data'];
        $no_of_points = $json_api->query->points;
        return array(
            'loan_amount_A' => $this->DVCtRound($no_of_points * $resort_data['option_a']),
            'loan_amount_B' => $this->DVCtRound($no_of_points * $resort_data['option_b']),
            'loan_amount_C' => $this->DVCtRound($no_of_points * $resort_data['option_c']),
                );
    }
```

Issue is, when i access this using http request, it shows 500 error. But when i try on localhost, it gives proper data. Below is request.
**/getDVCLoanAmount/?company_id=1&resort_code=AK&points=175**
I guess may be there is issue with using global variable ($json_api) two time??

Comment: Both methods are in same class.

Comment: No issue using the global twice. That won't be the problem. Can you get your 500 error to give you something more meaningful? Turn errors on at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` And see what details it gives you about the error.

Comment: It's also possible it has an issue with this: `$this->getDVCLoanResortData()['resort_data']`. I think older version of PHP doesn't like you accessing the array in the same line as executing the function, but don't quote me on that!